# How to create a self-signed certificate for iPhone?

Tags: ios, ssl

Charles the debugging proxy is able to create self-sign certificate for iOS, and I want to do the same with my testing app. So I use SSL to set up the connection between an iOS app and a server. The server's certificate is self-signed and will not be accepted by the iOS. I downloaded the certificate file to the iOS device I was using and manually installed it into the system, and it reads red text Not Verified. My app still fails to connect to the server (while the Android app could establish a connection just fine). Is there a way to create a self-signed trusted certificate for an iOS device like Charles the debugging proxy is able to do?

Comment: I think that this is now a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42455377/how-to-install-self-signed-certificate-in-ios-10, which is more recent but that I saw and answered first.